# Where is .config file is stored to make target linux image for a device

Tags: linux-kernel, config, linux-device-driver

I am attempting to compile a [custom linux kernel](https://github.com/rs-97-cfw/rs97-linux-kernel) with target device drivers defined in .config file.

When I open Github i can see the .config file is in the master/blob

However, once I download the repository, I cant find that .config file, but when i compile using makefile, it selects right device drivers.

So where exactly is .config is located?

Comment: *"So where exactly is .config is located?"* -- In the top-level directory of the kernel source; that is, the same directory from which you would issue the 'make' command to build the kernel.  Did you read the entire **README** file on how to *"compile using makefile"*?

Comment: @sawdust this is exactly why I am confused. In the Github top level directory I can see the .config but when I clone it to my home directory its not there neither .config.old. So does cloning process doesnt copy .config? I read the README file but it mentions about making config instead I am wondering why isnt .config copied from Github top-level directory to the clones top-level directory?

Comment: The creation/update of the **.config** file is the output of the `make myboard_defconfig` and `make menuconfig` commands.  Again, refer to the **README** for details.  Direct manipulation of the **.config** file is discouraged.  BTW the **.config** file is a *hidden* file; are you using the proper commands/tools that would show all files in a directory?

Comment: @sawdust, if direct manipulations are discouraged what `make menuconfig` and similar are doing then?!

Comment: @0andriy: `make menuconfig` allows to set options taking into account their **dependencies**. Because there are many dependencies between options in the Linux kernel, manually setting options has a high risk to break that dependencies. With incorrect dependencies building of the Linux kernel could suddenly fail with strange error. Or building could succeed but result would work improperly.

Comment: @sawdust thanks! Found them as they were hidden! Thanks again! You can put it as answer and I shall accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So where exactly is .config is located?

In the top-level directory of the kernel source; that is, the same directory from which you would issue the 'make' command to build the kernel.

Beware that the **.config** file is a *hidden* file; a filename that begins with a period is considered hidden.
Be sure you are using the proper commands/tools that would show all files in a directory.

Comment: it means that, the `.config` only appears after I build the kernel, right?

Comment: @xuanduc611 -- No, that's not right.  The **.config** file is needed to build the kernel, so it must exist before the kernel is built.

Comment: but I can't find it in the top-level directory of the kernel source. As you can see in this [link](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/), there is no `.config` file.

Comment: @xuanduc611 -- The information to resolve your confusion has already been posted above.  You need to read [my comment above to the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525758/where-is-config-file-is-stored-to-make-target-linux-image-for-a-device#comment115849259_65525758).  For more variations on kernel configuration, study the `Configuring the kernel` section in the [**README.rst**](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/README.rst) file.